# Как отнять от текстбокса значение?

Tags: c#, textbox

Столкнулся с проблемой - я хотел от текстбокса отнять значение переменной или значение. Вот код

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var balance = textBox1.Text;
    var ost = balance;
    var apple = 3;
    var watermelon = 15;
    var pumpkin = 24;
    var melon = 18;
    textBox6.Text = textBox1.Text;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox6 - apple;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: `textBox6.Text = (Int32.Parse(textBox6.Text) - apple).ToString();`

Comment: А что должна делать строка `textBox6 - apple`?

Comment: Я думал что строка textBox6 - apple будет отбавлять...

Comment: +1 за слово "отбавлять"

Comment: Если вам нужно получать числа от пользователя, то используйте `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не самая лучшая идея, у `NumericUpDown` есть ряд ограничений, плюс все равно придется делать приведение к нужному числовому типу из `Decimal`, лучше уж сразу научиться правильно парсить строку в число, и контролировать ввод данных пользователем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: У мня эта ошибка так и осталась предложите еще коды...

Answer (score 2):

`TextBox` работает только со строками. Даже если вы ввели туда число - то оно останется строкой символов, обозначающих это число.

Из утверждения выше следует, что после `var balance = textBox1.Text;`, `balance` будет иметь тип `string`. следовательно после `var ost = balance;` - `ost` будет тоже иметь тип `string`.

`textBox6 - apple;` это выражение компилятор не примет, т.к. оператор `-` не определен для типа `TextBox`.

**Как правильно?**

Есть разные способы решения, одно из них, в комментариях, предложил **@Alexander Petrov** - использовать для ввода чисел элемент [**NumericUpDown**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx) (примеры использования см. в документации по ссылке), но с ним тоже не все так просто. Во-первых этот контрол использует тип `Decimal` в качестве значений, и его все равно придется приводить к нужным вам числовым типам, например `int`. Во-вторых он требует явного указания максимального и минимального значений. В некоторых случаях это хорошо, в некоторых нет. В-третьих, контрол требует явного указания количества знаков после запятой и шаг для изменения значения стрелочками вверх/вниз, которые нельзя скрыть. Возможно перечисленные особенности  не будут являться недостатками в конкретно вашем случае, если так, то просто замените `TextBox` на `NumericUpDown`, и используйте явное приведение типов для передачи значений в ваши переменные, например так

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
или так 
int a = (int)numericUpDown1.value;
```

Другой вариант - преобразовать введенную в `TextBox` строку в число, если это возможно, а если не возможно (пользователь ввел не число) вывести сообщение об ошибке ввода или просто перекрасить фон, тем самым давая понять что, введенное значение не удовлетворяет требованиям программы.
Для реализации этого варианта нам потребуется примерно следующее:

1. Преобразование `string` в числовой тип.

   - использовать класс [**Convert**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) (примеры использования по ссылке)
   - использовать метод [**int.Parse**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) (примеры использования по ссылке)
   - использовать метод [**int.TryParse**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) (примеры использования по ссылке)

Первые два варианта приведут к исключению, при попытке преобразовать неверную входную строку. `TryParse`, в отличие от них, возвращает `true` если преобразование успешно и записывает преобразованное значение в переменную, переданную вторым параметром с обязательным модификатором `out`, либо `false` во всех остальных случаях, содержимое переменной в которую нужно поместить значение при этом не изменится. Это удобно, т.к. мы можем поместить вызов этого метода в условие `if`. К слову, `Convert`, `Parse`, и `TryParse` применимы для всех стандартных числовых типов.

2. Дать знать пользователю, что он ввел не верное значение

Это можно сделать по разному, но в любом случае нам потребуется знать что пользователь вообще что-то вводил. Для этого нужно воспользоваться событием [**TetxBox.TextChanged**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Там же по ссылке приведен пример с изменением цвета текста при некорректном вводе.

> я хотел от текстбокса отнять значение переменной

Для этого нужно, одним из приведенных выше способов, преобразовать значение `TextBox.Text` из `string` нужный числовой тип, выполнить вычитание из полученного значения и результат записать обратно в `TextBox.Text` представив числовое значение в виде строки с помощью метода `ToString()`, который для любого числового типа возвращает его символьное представление.

В случае использования `NumericUpDown` немного проще:

```
numericUpDown1.Value -= 10;
или
int a = 10;
numericUpDown1.Value -= a;
```

Ещё один важный момент - видимость переменных. Локальные переменные, которые вы объявляете в методе - видны только внутри этого метода. Это значит, что вы не можете обращаться к ним в других методах. Чтобы переменная была видна для всех методов класса - её нужно сделать полем или свойством класса и объявить за пределами метода, перед или после - не важно, главное не внутри.

Остается только выбрать, какое решение подходит вам больше и научиться применять его на практике.

Comment: +1, Но обратите внимание, что в вопросе ещё и проблема с видимостью переменных. Переменная apple объявляется на уровне одного блока, а используется в другом блоке.

Comment: @4per спасибо, об этом я как-то забыл, сейчас поправлю.